# asp.net Url routing not working with form authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication, url-routing

I am using the latest feature url routing but its not working. Before the code, following are the points you must know:

1. Its non MVC
2. I am using form authentication where i am redirecting user to login.aspx
3. Site is hosted on IIS6
4. Dev - VS 2010, .Net 4.0

Webconfig code:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    forms name=".COOKIEDEMl" timeout="90" loginUrl="~/User/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/index.aspx"/>
</authentication>
```

Global.asax code:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    SetRouting(RouteTable.Routes);           
}

private void SetRouting(RouteCollection routeCollection)
{
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Company",
    "Company/{CompanyName}",
    "~/Asset/RequestForm.aspx", true, new RouteValueDictionary { { "CompanyName", "?CompanyName" } });

    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Deal",
    "Company/{CompanyName}/{DealName}",
    "~/Asset/RequestForm.aspx", true, new RouteValueDictionary { { "DealName", "?DealName" } });
}
```

The user is not redirected to RequestForm.aspx when user types the url: `http://localhost/testprj/company/Gmail/?my deal`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass querystring parameters into the Route. Rather use route parameters. I.e. Do not use ?my-deal, rather use company/gmail/my-deal

Also, it is preferable not to use any spaces in your URL. Replace them with a hyphen (not underscore).